# recruitment agency asked for availability but no reply

Tags: interviewing

I went to interview at a recruitment agency and they said they would forward my resume to one of the companies.

They called me after 1 month and saying the company would like to have face to face interview with me. I emailed my availability to her. However, they have not got back to me after 4 days.  Should I send a follow-up email? If so, how should I ask them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should follow up for an update. Where the recruitment agent called you, you could call back rather than email. The two questions you're asking is:

- did you receive my email regarding availability? (*if you didn't receive a reply initially*)
- is there an update from the client?

You should focus on building a good relationship with your recruitment agent, picking up the phone and remaining in contact (when you're in the frame for a new role) helps to do this.